# Resharper C++ 2022 doesn't process newly added files (Visual Studio 2022)

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

When I add a new file to project, Resharper operates as this file is from an excluded directory, so it doesn't show any indicator, marker, ... absolutely nothing on that file until next restart of Visual Studio.

Any workarounds?

Comment: Please report this to ReSharper support and describe in details what you are doing. If you can attach a solution where this behavior can be reproduced, that would be great.